# Flash - comma , and period . keys don't trigger key down

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, keyboard

I've encountered a rather strange bug in Flash CS5.5:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyDwn);

function onKeyDwn(e:KeyboardEvent){
    trace("Key down!");
}
```

The keys command and period on a standard US keyboard does not trigger key down events for me. However, if I add a textbox and type in it, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable keyboard shortcuts in the flash player. Select Test Movie in Flash CS5.5, and when the flash player window appears make sure Control -> Disable Keyboard Shortcuts is checked in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set focus manually:

```
stage.focus = stage;
```

Following code is working for me right in cs5.5:

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

stage.focus = stage;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,onKeyDwn);

function onKeyDwn(e:KeyboardEvent){
    trace("Key down!");
}
```